# Send commands directly in running process and indirectly (e. g. with tail)

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, minecraft

I am currently building a docker project for running a Minecraft Spigot server.

To achieve this I need to be able to run commands in the running shell (when using `docker run -it d3strukt0r/spigot`) and indirectly with `docker exec <name> console <command>`. Unfortunately, I'm not too fond of the bash language.

Currently, I am able to send commands indirectly, which is great when being detached. I got this with:

```sh
_console_input="/app/input.buffer"
# Clear console buffers
true >$_console_input

# Start the main application
echo "[....] Starting Minecraft server..."
tail -f $_console_input | tee /dev/console | $(command -v java) $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar /app/spigot.jar --nogui "$@"
```

And when running the console command, all it does is the following:

```sh
echo "$@" >>/app/input.buffer
```

The code can be found [here](https://github.com/D3strukt0r/docker-spigot/tree/develop/bin)

Does someone know a way of how to be able to now add the functionality to directly enter commands?

**USE CASE ONE: A user may run attached using `docker run`**

```sh
docker run -it --name spigot -p 25565:25565 -e EULA=true d3strukt0r/spigot:nightly
```

In this case, the user should definitely be able to use the console as he is used to (when running `java -jar spigot.jar`).
If he has a second console open he can also send a command with:

```sh
docker exec spigot console "time set day"
```

**USE CASE TWO: A user may run detached using `docker run -d`**

```sh
docker run -d --name spigot -p 25565:25565 -e EULA=true d3strukt0r/spigot:nightly
```

In this case, the user is only able to send commands indirectly.

```sh
docker exec spigot console "time set day"
```

**USE CASE THREE AND FOUR: Use docker-compose (look at the use case "two", it's basically the same)**

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong you want to pass <command> directly at the time of running container and want a container to be run continuously?

Comment: Thanks, seems I was not clear enough. Please look at the use cases I added @NiteshSharma <command> is sent, while the server is still running and that's all. It's like a user would send a command, but right now it's done by listening to file changes.

Comment: you didn't mention another use case when a user can run docker in detach mode and run command going inside container 
 `docker exec -it spigot bash`  it directly open bash inside the container I didn't get what is mean by directly enter commands?

Comment: the use cases are just to help understand how to implement the functionality @NiteshSharma . All it has to be able to do is to directly enter commands and also indirectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a script that acts like a mini-shell, reading from stdin and writing to `/app/input.buffer`. Set it as the container's `CMD` so it runs by default. Put it in the same directory as your `Dockerfile` and make sure it's executable.

**interactive_console**

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS= read -rp '$ ' command; do
    printf '%s\n' "$command"
done >> /app/input.buffer
```

**Dockerfile**

```
COPY interactive_console /usr/bin
CMD interactive_console
```

Comment: I love this answer. I can't use `CMD` though. my `ENTRYPOINT` already starts the `docker-entrypoint.sh` which then starts the server. So I basically added `&` at the end of the line, followed by `interactive_console`. This fixes this, but this makes it even more difficult to figure out how I can close the server by pressing `CTRL + C`. Could this somehow be implemented in this script? (just execution `console stop` when pressing `CTRL + C` would be fair enough.

Comment: Alright, the first time I encounter that I can't edit my own comment. Anyways, testing the code shows that `CTRL + C` will just close the container, no clean shutdown, nothing .